# End up with black screen with blinking cursor. Screen refreshes each 2 seconds

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 20.04, login-screen

I have a dual boot installation on my old PC with Windows8 and Ubuntu 20.04.
The computer configuration reads:

Procesor: Intel Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU E5700 @ 3.00GHz

GPU: NVidia GeForce GT 220 1024 MB

Motherboard: ASUSTeK Computer INC. P5G41C-M LX(LGA775)

RAM: 4.00 GB Dual-Channel DDR3 @ 399M Hz (6-6-6-15)

HDD: 931 GB Western Digital WDC WD10EZEX-00BN5AO ATA Device (SATA)

The dual boot used to work fine 2 months ago. I stopped using this computer for 2 months.

Today I booted Ubuntu 20.04 and it worked fine, but some problems with the software update app appeared.
These didn't allow me to install python3.8 using apt from the PPA deadsnakes repo. This has made me search for solutions to the errors which appeared when writing `$sudo apt get-install python3.8`. I don't remember what I did, but now when boot the Ubuntu, it goes past the logo display at the bottom of the screen and ends up with a white blinking cursor on a black screen. This blinking cursor doesn't stay there all the times, from time to time the screen ''refreshes itself'' - that is, it goes totally black for a second or so, then the cursor reappears. This process repeats indefinitely.

I can login into recovery mode of the Ubuntu 20.04 via the GRUB thing. This is how I choose between Windows and Ubuntu 20.04 in the first place, so it always worked and now it works as well.
I tried to login into recovery mode and then to resume to normal booting. The screen goes totally black for most of the time, and for time to time a white blinking cursor appears for 1 second or so.
I know the sudo password.

Please, can you help me repair this? I am really worried I cannot access ubuntu anymore and I need it to compute things for work. Windows works fine.
I do not know what to do.
Ctrl+Alt+F* seem to work only for F4, but the tty4 doesn't stay on the screen for me to write on it. It disappears very quickly and I don't have time to write anything. If I press again Ctrl+Alt+F4, the tty4 appears again, but same ''restarting process'' comes into play. It stores what I wrote previously, though.

### EDITS from COMMENTS

gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/gdm.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)

Active: inactice (dead)

[output of command dmesg --level=err,warn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vH1g5.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to add this as comment but not available for me ,

try to stop the display manager in the tty4 that is working partially

check the running dm and include the output to your question too

```
systemctl status display-manager.service
```

then stop it (gdm3/lightdm)

```
sudo service gdm3 stop
```

or

```
sudo systemctl stop gdm3
```

and check the journal `journalctl -xe` to see what's failing that causes this behavior and include the errors in your question

add the output of  `dmesg --level=err,warn` to your question

Comment: I am trying to write that command sudo service lightdm stop in the tty4 ( with consecutive invocations of ctrl+alt+f4 ) but I always get login incorrect ... it looks like it thinks about the password I enter for a bit, then goes black, and I need to re-press ctrl+alt+f4 to get back to the message login incorrect

Comment: how long it takes before the screen goes blank ?

Comment: maximum 1-2 seconds

Comment: shall I try to run the commands in your answer inside the recovery mode of Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: when the screen appears in which you choose which operating system to start press e then replace `quiet splash` to `nomodeset`

Comment: please see the updated question for the outputs of the commands you told me to run

Comment: great now the screen is not blinking try to install different display manager , uninstall gdm `sudo apt purge gdm` , then install lightdm `sudo apt-get install lightdm`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122798/discussion-between-velenos14-and-samyabdellatif).